# Wordpress: Show Latest Post on Post Template, but don't when on the Latest Post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom blog page `content-single.php` which outputs a custom template.

I've outputted the most recent post of a specific category, but the issue is, if you're on the most recent post of that category, you see a link to that post, which has no benefit.

So Basically,

Title: "Why Design is Important"
Content: Output post content
Most Recent Design Blog: "Why Design is Important"

Here's my code (my PHP knowledge isn't all that great, so apologies). If anyone can help to get it to not show this block it is the latest post.

Many thanks,

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'category_name' => 'design'
);

$q = new WP_Query( $args);

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();        
?>
<div class="col-12">
  <?php include("inc/components/blog-card-snippet.php"); ?>
</div>

<?php
    } // end while
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
?>
    <div class="col">
        <p>No Blogs marked as <strong>Design</strong> to show</p>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

**ANSWER**

The fix courtesy of [Alexandru Burca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538109/alexandru-burca) was to update the `$args` to include `post__not_in`.

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'category_name' => 'design',
  'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID())
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `post__not_in`. Change **$args** to

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'category_name' => 'design',
  'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID())
);
```

More info here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

Comment: Thanks for this Alexandru, it does exactly what I want. Will update my post and mark this as the answer.